# Toggle Google Maps API fusionLayer with anchor

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, onclick, toggle, navbar

http://rickgutierrez.bol.ucla.edu/map_mobile6.htm

I am working on a mobile map using google maps API and JQuery Mobile v1.2. I stored spatial data (the bikeway polyline layer and the bike rack point layer) in google fusion tables and displayed them on the map. I would like to toggle each layer on/off using the bike and park anchors in the JQuery navbar. I have exeperience toggling layers on/off with checkboxes on desktop maps but prefer the look and size of the navbar toggling for the mobile map.

My ideal functionality would be for the map to load with the bike layer on and the bike portion of the navbar darker to denote that it is selected, just like on other web apps. A user can use the map to find safer biking routes with bike layer then turn on the bike parking layer at their destination to find a place to lock their bike. Each layer can be toggled on and off independently.

I tried pasting the code in here but it was a mess. Please look review my source code at the above link. I am a novice at coding and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Update: I guess someone commented that if geolocation is denied the map does not work. here is the geolocation code:

```
// allow iPhone or Android to track movement
        if ( useragent.indexOf('iPhone') !== -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') !== -1 ) {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( 
                displayLocation, 
                handleError, 
                { 
                    enableHighAccuracy: true, 
                    maximumAge: 30000, 
                    timeout: 27000 
                }
            );          

        // or let other geolocation capable browsers to get their static position
        } else if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( displayLocation, handleError );
        }
```

How do I fix that? I am guessing that I need to put some backup coordinates into the else statement?

Comment: Your map doesn't work if I deny geolocation.

Comment: I would like for the map to open and load exactly where the user is. Google Maps runs a bit slow on mobile phones so it will improve the experience if you don't have to wait for the map to open in a location you are not in (say I tell the map to open and center on downtown) then have to swipe to find where you actually are. How would I pass a standard geocoordinate to the map if a user denies the geolocation?

Comment: How to fix the geolocation problem is a different question.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp I reviewed the information here and tried to change the item that does the activates the toggling "button" into the ID of the anchor that I want to press to toggle the map layer. I changed the thing being toggled "p" into the name that I used to store the map variable.

Comment: Why would you expect that to work for Google Maps API objects?

Comment: //Function to toggle single layers on/off
  rick.toggleLayer = function(layer,id)
  {
      
   if ($('#'+id).is(':checked'))
   {
    layer.setMap(map);
   }
   else
   {
    layer.setMap(null);
   }
  }                                                        //this is what I was using to toggle the desktop map I created but it only works with checkboxes. I attempted to change the .is to .click but the .click is really a boolean that works with the if else statement. Can I use the css active state for the anchor for the if else?

Comment: I'm new to this so I often don't know what to expect. Just trial and error when I am attempting to figure something out.

Comment: The only part of this "rick.toggleLayer = function(layer,id) { if ($('#'+id).is(':checked')) { layer.setMap(map); } else { layer.setMap(null); } }" that is specific to checkboxes is the $('#'+id).is(':checked')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a google.maps.event.addDomListener listening for a click event to the elements that you want to perform the toggle.  In the function associated with that listener add your code to toggle the layer.

I would suggest:

```
if (layer.getMap() == null) layer.setMap(map); else layer.setMap(null);
```

where "map" is a reference to your google.maps.Map object.

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_layertoggle_map_mobile6c.html)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events I reviewed the information here to figure out how to properly set up google.maps.event.addDomListener. One question, I have to tell the function what will be clicked which in my case is a <li> in the navbar won't I run into the same issue where the google maps api code won't  accept the html id?